# How to catch any click event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button, when it's clicked, shows a div with images(like an emoticon panel of a chat) if I click it again the div hides, but what I want to do is:
If the div is already showed up and then I click any other thing of the page, I want to hide it. I tried this:

```
$("myBtn").click(function(){
    // show div
});

$(document).click(function(){
// hide div
});
```

When "myBtn" is clicked, the div shows up and hide automatically. How could I fix it ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I tried catching the click events like this:
$("div").click(function(){//} but it executes the code inside for every div element in the webpage. So it shows and hide the div

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
$(document).on('click', function(evt) {
    if(!$(evt.target).is('#my-id')) {
        //Hide
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Just so you can have a full working set:

```
$('#mybutton').on('click', function(evt) {
    $('#mydiv').show();
    return false;//Returning false prevents the event from continuing up the chain
});
```

Comment: @chad and @Mathletics Thank you.  `.on` should be used for all events.  :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the difference between .on('click', ...) and .click(...) ? Is one preferred over the other?

Comment: @CharlieKilian `click` has always been sugar for `bind("click")`; on obviates all of them and includes the new simple delegation syntax of `.on(event, childSelector, callback)`

Comment: +1 to @Mathletics for that explanation.  For more information, here is the link to the jQuery site: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Useful explanation. Return false made my day ... Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

At the same time you show your original `<div>`, add a new `<div>` to your page that has a style/css set like this:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Make sure the original `<div>` -- the one you want to be able to click on without closing it -- has a higher `z-index`, but everything else on the page has a lower z-index.

When you add the new div to your page, give it the `.ui-widget-overlay` class, and add a click handler to intercept clicks on that `<div>`. Adding the overlay div with the click handler looks like this:

```
$('<div class="ui-widget-overlay">')
    .click(function() {
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').remove();
        $('selector-for-original-div').hide();
    })
    .appendTo('body');
```

The upshot of all this: You have two divs. The first is what you want to display and allow users to click in without closing it, the second is an invisible div underneath the first taking up the entire browser window so that if the user clicks anywhere but the upper div, it intercepts the click event. Inside that click event, you remove the hidden div and hide the original.

Comment: Yes this is a common implementation but it's pretty tangential to the actual question.

Comment: This method works too but talking about efficiency, the answer above is the best one. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

*updated*

Assuming that you have a class 'active' to the element when it shows, it would be:

```
$('html').click(function(e){

  if(!$(e.target).attr("id") == "my-id") { 

  }

});
```

Comment: Close, but really ugly when it doesn't need to be.

Comment: @Chad, thank you for your comment. How will you do it ? I will be happy to improve my code.

Comment: You cleaned up most of it, but you are binding to `'html'` which isn't "wrong" but convention is to bind to `document`.

Comment: Thank you, I learn 2 things the 'on' and the use of 'document' in this situation. Will fix my code. Cheers. B.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('body').click(function() {
   if($("div").is(':visible')){
    $("div").hide();
   }
  });
</script>
```

the $("div") selector here should be your div that is either has id or class for example: if the `<div class="class" id="id">` then `$("div")` will be changed to `$("div.class")` or `$("div#id")`

Comment: you may want to be more specific than `"div"` in the selector, especially as a generic example which OP is likely to use explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @Mathletics I added explanation.

Comment: Don't ever use `$('div#id')` since that is over specifying and will actually make Sizzle unable to use `getElementById()` optimizations.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="slControlWrapper">
    <div class="slControlLabel">
        <asp:Label ID="lblSL" CssClass="lblSL" runat="server">Clickable Label</asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="slControlSeparator">

    </div>
    <div class="slControlDropDown">

    </div>
     <div id="wndSL">
        This is the hidden content of my DIV Window
    </div>
    <div id="test">
    I am for test click on me
    </div>
</div>


 $('.slControlLabel, .slControlDropDown').bind('click',function(event){

   $('#wndSL').show(); 
 event.stopPropagation();
 });


$('html').click(function() {
   $('#wndSL').hide(); 
});


    #wndSL {

display:none;     background-color: blue;    height:500px;    width:590px;
}
```

Have a gander here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nCZmz/26/

Comment: Works to me, just clicky click there sir.

Comment: I understand `wnd` is Hungarian for Window, but what is `sl`?

Comment: Why do you have ASP control tags in your solution?

Comment: -1 Ugly, and clicking in the shown div still hides which is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps `sl` means "server label"? I still don't understand the semantics

Comment: This answer uses ASP.NET server controls, but it wasn't tagged as an ASP.NET question.